# Exception Handling in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller that currently looks like this:

```
def create
  begin
    @gift_card = GiftCard.create(gift_card_params)
  rescue Exception => e
    capture_exception(e)
    flash[:alert] = e.message
    redirect_to :root
  else
    render :confirmation
  end
end
```

This is working fine when an exception is raised in the model- my question is about what's really going on here. I wanted to insert a `fail` in the controller to take a look at the exception, like so:

```
def create
  begin
    @gift_card = GiftCard.create(gift_card_params)
  rescue Exception => e
    capture_exception(e)
    flash[:alert] = e.message
    fail
    redirect_to :root
  else
    render :confirmation
  end
end
```

I would expect that checking __better_errors would show the controller failing where the `fail` statement is placed. However, it actually stops the action inside of the model, in the method where the exception is actually raised:

```
raise payment.error_message if payment.error_message.present?
```

Why is the `fail` above not getting triggered?

Comment: Note that by catching `Exception` you're also catching things like syntax errors and such. You'd probably want to catch `StandardError` instead.

Comment: this is really overkill, try running a `rails g scaffold books title:string` and look at the controller that generates.  You have access to errors in a much more `rails-like` way